# Javascript display dynamic position text popup into image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image, that show two or more products, where I would like to open a text popup(or a tooltip) with the product description. Different products can be placed in different position in image. There is a tool or a method that if I insert the coordinate(X:Y) of product can compose the image and with hover or click show the popup/tooltip?
An example can be find on ikea site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the map/area properties of HTML5 to achieve this.

Refer [link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_imagemap.asp)